# How to rename the 'save' and 'cancel' button in cfgrid when mode="edit"?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-8, coldfusion-9, cfgrid

How to rename the 'save' and 'cancel' button in cfgrid when mode="edit"?  My CF app is not even in English.  If we can customize the text through `insertButton` and `deleteButton`, how come CF doesn't include `saveButton` & `cancelButton` in `<cfgrid>`?

http://cfbugs.adobe.com/cfbugreport/flexbugui/cfbugtracker/main.html#bugId=86593

Comment: you haven't specified the format that you are using..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct way in CF. But you can check extJS latest plugin.

http://edspencer.net/2009/09/using-the-extjs-row-editor.html
Sample URL : http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/examples/grid/row-editor.html